# drupal views autocomplete redirect on click, is it possible?

Tags: redirect, drupal, autocomplete, view

How can i do a redirect to node on views autocomplete exposed field result?

Is that possible?

i have an answer from here but is on an older version: https://www.drupal.org/node/1075068

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery listen for the change event on the autocomplete and submit the form.

```
$('#myautocomplete').change(function(){
  $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Comment: thanks, but my flow i want is like this:

users types in autocomplete flow -> results apears -> clck on one result from autocomplete dropdown -> redirects to that result page

Comment: confusing. Is result page the filtered view or the node page? The above code should submit the exposed form and display the view result.

Comment: If it is to redirect to the node page, I am confused as to why you would want an exposed filter to go to the node.

Comment: the exposed form is on the view page, if i submit the form with the result from autocomplete it will filter my result,

I want to redirect to the autocomplete result page

in the autocomplete dropdown i have the nodes title.

Comment: Why do you want to use a views exposed filter as a jump menu? Sounds to me like you might want to rethink your view and workflow.  I don't think I have any more suggestions.

Comment: I'm agree with @2pha , you must re-think your functionality logic.